# nth-of-type including other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of items where after certain items there is to be a spacer. I've tried to use `:nth-of-type` to apply styling to the first column of items that I don't want applied to the right side. However, the CSS seems to get confused when I have the separators.

https://jsfiddle.net/yquw291h/2/

As you can see the counting goes off after each extra div, but surely the CSS should only be taking into account each `.box`?

Is there a way I can make it only affect each item? I want only the first column to have certain styles, I'm happy to use a JS solution too.

HTML

```
<div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.box:nth-of-type(odd){
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: red;
}

.splitter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: I have nominated this question for reopening since this is asking for a JavaScript/jQuery solution and the target question was strictly CSS-only (and the answers are different; in CSS you can't, but with JS you can).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a misunderstanding of `:nth-of-type()`. It's looking for the *type* of element (a div), that is also (odd), and only applying the styles to those that are also of `class="box"`.

Your 5th div is a splitter, which is still counted even though it doesn't have `class="box"`. It just doesn't have the styles applied because your selector specifies **`.box`** nth-of-type. Your next odd one is `<div class="box">2</div>` in between the splitters.

In case you haven't caught on yet, it's counting all the divs in your container. Just because you have an even number as text inside the `.box` divs, doesn't make them evenly numbered entries in your "list" of divs.

Since you said in a comment that you can't edit the markup, here is a jQuery implementation (thanks to BoltClock for help):

```js
var container = document.getElementById("search-results");
var descendants = container.getElementsByTagName("div");
var x, i = 0;
for (x = 0; x < descendants.length; x++) {
    var nth = $(descendants).eq(x);
    if (nth.hasClass("splitter")) {
     i = 0;
     continue;
    }
    if (nth.hasClass("box")) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            nth.addClass("odd");
        }
        i++;
    }
};
```

```css
.box {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.odd {
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: red;
}

.splitter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-results">
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
</div>
```

You can modify your markup as Tim's answer suggests to achieve what you're looking for without using JavaScript. Or you can modify it by using a different set of elements to divide. But this would only work if you had an **even** number of divs in each section between a divider: (I've commented the numbering status for each element, with regard to the selector you're using).

```css
.box {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.box:nth-of-type(odd){
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: red;
}

.splitter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="box">1</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">4</div> <!-- even -->
    <hr class="splitter"/> <!-- N/A -->
    <div class="box">1</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- even -->
    <hr class="splitter"/> <!-- N/A -->
    <div class="box">1</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">4</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">5</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">6</div> <!-- odd -->
    <div class="box">7</div> <!-- even -->
    <div class="box">8</div> <!-- odd -->
</div>
```

At this point the question needs to be asked, why do you need columns? If you have some kind of tabular data, you should use `<table>`s. If you just want two side-by-side columns, why not put one group of divs in a "left" container and the others in a "right" container? That way you can style them en masse via `.left div {}` and `.right div {}` selectors.

Comment: @Tim You misunderstand. I've said it doesn't count meaning it doesn't *qualify* for the selector. This is in line with the rest of my answer. I'll edit it to make it clearer.

Comment: You could add a snippet with different type of element for the separators (like `hr`) and style it according to OP's separator. Just to supply an alternative solution. :)

Comment: @Tim True, but for now I'm headed to lunch :-P

Comment: Unfortunately, The structure is built on the fly as a search results page so adding different structure to the page isn't as easy as it would seem.

Comment: @SamWillis Can you add a classname or ID to the container div?

Comment: Yes I would be able to add to the container. It also already does have an ID of `search-results`

Comment: @SamWillis I've updated my answer to include a jQuery answer that does exactly what you want without modifying the markup/structure.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it works like it should. `:nth-of-type` translates to the number of this type (div) **of the parent element**. Therefor you can easily fix your problem by wrapping the boxes in a simple parent element, between separators:

```css
.box {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.box:nth-of-type(odd){
    margin-right: 4%;
    background-color: red;
}

.splitter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
  </div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
  </div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
  <div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div>
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, The structure is built on the fly as a search results page so adding different structure to the page isn't as easy as it would seem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a misunderstanding of how the [`:nth-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type) selector works. The `.box` selector doesn't restrict the `:nth-of-type` selector. It acts as an additional sub filter. In this case all odd divs are selected and then of those odd divs, ones with the `box` class are styled.

In your example, the odd divs in this case are:

```
<div>
    <div class="box">1</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div> <!-- Odd -->
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div> <!-- Odd -->
</div>
```

However, of those odd `divs` listed above, only these:

```
<div>
    <div class="box">1</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box -->
    <div class="box">2</div>
    <div class="box">3</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box -->
    <div class="box">4</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box -->
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
    <div class="box">1</div>
    <div class="box">2</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box-->
    <div class="box">3</div>
    <div class="box">4</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box -->
    <div class="box">5</div>
    <div class="box">6</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box -->
    <div class="box">7</div>
    <div class="box">8</div> <!-- Odd w/ class box-->
</div>
```

Match the additional filter requirements being that they must also contain the class `box`.

**Example:**

Below is an example of how you can accomplish this using several [`:nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selectors to create css ranges. This is helpful if you're not able to alter your HTML structure as some of the other answers suggest:

```css
.box {
  width: 48%;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.box:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+4),
.box:nth-child(n+6):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+8),
.box:nth-child(n+10):nth-child(even):nth-child(-n+17),
.box:nth-child(n+19):nth-child(odd):nth-child(-n+21){
  margin-right: 4%;
  background-color: red;
}

.splitter {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="splitter">splitter</div>
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** The above markup is slightly more extensive than that provided in your question. It's based off of your full jsfiddle markup instead of the shortened version contained in your question.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/yquw291h/9/) is your fiddle updated to contain the changes shown above.

Comment: What about browser support?

Comment: @Tim [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3). The CSS3 `:nth-child` selector has support in all major browsers and even partial support in IE 8.

Comment: And do you know that also covers the `n+x` part? Personally, I doubt that.

Comment: @Tim Yes, all except for IE 8 which was noted above. Here's two additional resources showing browser support [`:nth-child`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/#browser-support) and [How `nth-child` works](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/#article-header-id-0) if you still have doubts...

Comment: Smart solution then!

Comment: @Tim Thanks! Yours too. I personally like the idea of fixing the HTML structure to support the desired layout but if its locked in as the OP says, it's good to have a backup.

Comment: This would definitely work (albeit a little verbosely) if the structure were static, but it's built on the fly (per OP's comment on my answer above).